# How do I add shadow in Bootstrap 3 Tooltip?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm trying to a shadow in Bootstrap 3 Tooltip.

I have a code here: https://codepen.io/aceraven777/pen/ExQXOWq

When I try to add a shadow, its covering the arrow:

```
.tooltip {
    box-shadow: rgb(118 118 118 / 35%) 0px 0px 17px 8px;
}
```

I'm not much of a CSS expert, can somebody guide me here?

Comment: You need to target `.tooltip-inner` https://codepen.io/sparxia/pen/xxYrQmV https://nimb.ws/1KrJRP

Comment: You can add like this `.tooltip-inner { box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;}`